# Behaviour of $f$ in the neighbourhood of $c$ if $f'(c)= \cdots = f^{(n)}(c)=0$, and $f^{(n+1)}(c) \gt 0$

Tags: calculus

What can I say about the behaviour of $f$ in the neighbourhood of $c$ if
$f'(c)= \cdots = f^{(n)}(c)=0$, and $f^{(n+1)}(c) \gt 0$? I know the behaviour of $f$ if $n \le 2$, but I do not know how to generalize this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think you can say about the behavior of $f(x)=(x-c)^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ approximately looks like (in the Taylor series sense) $(x-c)^{n+1}$. Conclude from that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ has a strict ascneding saddle point if $n$ is even and a strict local minimum if $n$ is odd. You should know this for the case $n\le2$. To go from $n$ to $n+1$, you know by induction that $f'$ has a strict minimum or strict ascending saddle point at $c$, that is $f'$ is strictly positive for $x>c$, $x\approx c$ and either strictly positive or negative for $x<c$, $x\approx c$, from which you conclude that $f$ has a saddle point or minimum, respectively.

Another proof: Show that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{(x-c)^2}$ is continuous at $c$, and look at $g'(c),\ldots , g^{(n-1)}(c)$. What can you conclude about $f$?